# PHP - PSExec Output not showing

Tags: php, batch-file, psexec

I believe this is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351407/php-not-reading-psexec-output) but no solution was provided.

I have a query which uses PSExec to do a net session ona  profile server, and it works fine when put in from the command line like below:

```
psexec \\profile-server -u username -p password net session
```

It will show the PSExec banner (from stderr) and then the query results (from stdout).

However, when I run this from PHP I can only see the stderr feed (both when sending to the screen or to file) but can't see stdout at all. When I redirect stdout to a file the file is blank.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    $uname_prof = "DOMAIN-USERNAME";
    $pw_prof = "DOMAIN-PASSWORD";
    $ip = "PROFILE-SERVER";

    $query = "psexec.exe \\\\$ip -u $uname_prof -p $pw_prof net session";

    $result = exec($query, $output);

    echo implode('<br>', $output);
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: A side comment - from the cmd if I navigate to c:\xampp\php and run the command "php.exe filename.php" then it shows the stdout fine (either to cmd line or to file) but, again, not when run through a web browser.

Comment: try with xcmd - http://feldkir.ch/xcmd.htm

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you want to combine stderr and stdout so you have all the output from psexec.exe in the $output variable:

```
$query = "psexec.exe \\\\$ip -u $uname_prof -p $pw_prof net session 2>&1";
```

if that's right just put 2>&1 at the end of your command

here is link with more info about redirect stderr [Is there a way to redirect ONLY stderr to stdout (not combine the two) so it can be piped to other programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273866/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-only-stderr-to-stdout-not-combine-the-two-so-it-can)

Comment: This yields the same results, the stderr (psexec banner) will show but the stdout is still nowhere to be seen.